# Alguém pode me dizer se existe uma forma mais fácil ou correta de chamar dois selects de tabelas diferentes?

Tags: c#

```
using BRQ_Jobs.Modelo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BRQ_Jobs.DAL
{
    public class PesquisaDALComandos
    {
        string conecta = @"Integrated Security = SSPI; Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog = BRQ_JOBS; Data Source = NBBV027097";
        SqlConnection conexao = null;
        SqlCommand comando;

        CadastroRecrutador recrutador = new CadastroRecrutador();
        CadastroVagas vaga = new CadastroVagas();

        //Método para listar os dados do banco
        public DataTable Listar()
        {           
            try
            {
                using (conexao = new SqlConnection(conecta))                    
                {                   
                    if (!recrutador.Equals(vaga))
                    {
                        comando = new SqlCommand("select distinct COD_REC,NOME,SITUACAO from RECRUTADOR", conexao);                                     
                    }
                    else if (!vaga.Equals(recrutador))
                    {
                        comando = new SqlCommand("select distinct COD_VAGA,NOME,DESCRICAO,SALARIO,SITUACAO from VAGA", conexao);
                    }
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.SelectCommand = comando;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Método para pesquisar ao digitar
        public DataTable Pesquisar(PesquisaModel pesquisa)
        {
            try
            {
                using (conexao = new SqlConnection(conecta))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    if (!recrutador.Equals(vaga))
                    {
                        comando = new SqlCommand("select distinct COD_REC,NOME,SITUACAO from RECRUTADOR where NOME like '%' + @nome + '%' order by NOME", conexao);                   
                    }
                    else if (!vaga.Equals(recrutador))
                    {
                        comando = new SqlCommand("select distinct COD_VAGA,NOME,DESCRICAO,SALARIO,SITUACAO from VAGA where NOME like '%' + @nome + '%' order by NOME", conexao);
                    }

                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", pesquisa.Nome);
                    da.SelectCommand = comando;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Primeiro você está fazendo errado, usando `SqlDataAdapter` para retornar um `DataTable` não é necessário, além do desempenho muito baixo. Só o seu código não tem como ajudar muito, precisa melhorar a sua pergunta

Answer (score 0):

É sim possível. Para isso é preciso usar o `UNION`. Tomando o seu caso como exemplo:

```sql
SELECT COD, Nome
FROM (
  SELECT COD_REC AS COD, Nome
  FROM RECRUTADOR
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COD_VAGA, Nome
  FROM VAGA
) AS t1
WHERE t1.COD = 1
```

Segue link com exemplo no SQl Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99ffc/9/0

Comment: é os outros campos? só pode fazer union com a mesma quantidade de campos, isso não vai funcionar